# Why does my sonarqube give 0% coverage while I have unit tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube, spring-test

So I am using SonarQube to improve my code. The problem is that I keep getting 0% coverage. I think my build.gradle file is not correct, but I am not sure that is the problem. Can anyone check for me if my build.gradle is correct or not so that if this is not the problem I keep looking what else is the problem.

**My build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.2.0"
    id 'jacoco'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '15'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    implementation('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.2')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.4.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.4.2.201908231537-r'
    /**
     * JUnit jupiter with mockito.
     */
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-junit-jupiter', version: '2.19.0'

    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.19.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'
}

sonarqube{
    properties{
        property 'sonarjava.source', '1.8'
        property 'sonar.java.coveragePlugin', 'jacoco'
        property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths', 'build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml'
        property 'sonar.java.test.binaries'
    }
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: During the build when Sonarqube is doing its thing it usually outputs something about reading Jacoco coverage reports. What does it say? Can it find the reports?

Comment: @WoutervanderLinde this is my output:
 Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 27s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date

Answer (score 1):

The key is that the SonarQube scanner has to know where the jacoco data file resides.  The pervasive annoyance with property-based development is that it's unlikely you will ever see an error message saying you didn't set the correct property.  That's what happened in this case.

This depends a bit on what version of SonarQube you're working with, but the property you're setting, "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", was never intended to point to the Jacoco XML file.  The correct property is "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths".

Comment: When I try to replace the sonar.jacoco.reportPaths with your line of code I get the following error:
No coverage report can be found with sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml'. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco
/test/jacocoTestReport.xml

Comment: If it says it is not found, then you need to figure out where the file is being created. I can't tell you that. The property needs to point to its location.

Answer (score 0):

Add **jacocoTestReport** task in build.gradle

```
jacocoTestReport {
reports {
    xml.enabled true
}
```

}

Run -->

```
gradle build jacocoTestReport sonarqube
```

This SonarSource Guide might help you to understand it better
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151

Check build.gradle in this sample project provided in SonarQube documentation -- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/blob/master/sonarqube-scanner-gradle/gradle-basic/build.gradle